# Is there a way to programmatically retrieve Cloud9 ssh key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-cli, aws-cloud9

I plan to setup a training environment in an automated way using terraform. I´d like to make use of Cloud9 to keep the efforts low on attendees site. I know there are 2 ways to setup a cloud9 environment:

1. EC2 based
2. With an existing instance
   The first option is easy to achieve.

However, I´d like to setup the instance automatically and preconfigure it so that it can then directly be used by the attendees. Therefore, I need to add the Cloud9´s public ssh key to the authorized keys file, but I didn´t find a way to get this programmatically (neither in terraform, nor with the cli).

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It's `AWSCloud9WorkspaceManagementService.GetUserPublicKey`, which is not exposed beyond the web console interface.  However, afaik, the public key has the same lifecycle as the IAM user itself.  That said, it's probably easiest to create a custom AMI and just use it with the API or Terraform, allowing Cloud9 to manage the lifecycle as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. At least I know now that I didn´t oversee sth. - it´s just not possible :-)
To be honest I don´t get the last part of your comment. Can you please elaborate a bit on this?